# Is there a way to create a two or more XML tags with the same name on Nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I'm running the following code using `xml2js` to create my XML from a JSON struct. I have the following code:

```
const xml2js = require('xml2js')

const JSONObject = {
  order: {
    client: 'thomas',
    itens: {
      item: {
        id: 1
      },
      item: {
        id: 2
      }
    }
  }
}

const builder = new xml2js.Builder();
const xml = builder.buildObject(JSONObject);
console.log(xml)
```

With the following output:

```
<order>
  <client>thomas</client>
  <itens>
    <item>
      <id>2</id>
    </item>
  </itens>
</order>
```

What can i do so the output is something like this?

```
<order>
  <client>thomas</client>
  <itens>
    <item>
      <id>1</id>
    </item>
    <item>
      <id>2</id>
    </item>
  </itens>
</order>
```

Thanks so much in advance! :)

Comment: That's an array of item`[]`

Comment: @Matt D*mn, I can't believe it was that easy! Thank you so much <3

Comment: @GabrielBelloni Could you please write a complete answer so it's more easy to see this post when querying for the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

like :

```
additionalInfo: 
 { 
   info: 
    [
       { infoName: "a", infoValue: 10 },
       { infoName: "a b", infoValue: 20 }, 
       { infoName: "a b c", infoValue: 30 }, 
       { infoName: "a b c d", infoValue: 40 }
     ] 
 },
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).